# Easier way to write conditional statement

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there any prettier way to write this if-statement:

```
if not (self.is_legal(l) or self.is_legal(u) or self.is_legal(r) or self.is_legal(d)):
```

I've tried this, but it didn't work.

```
if not self.is_legal(l or r or d or u):
```

Or maybe the first one is the prettiest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
if not any(self.is_legal(x) for x in (l, u, r, d)):
```

Or, if you prefer [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) instead of `any`:

```
if all(not self.is_legal(x) for x in (l, u, r, d)):
```

The first solution seems to read a little better though.

---

As for why your attempted solution did not work, the `or` operator in Python does not behave as you think it does.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-or_test):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value
>   is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

So, `self.is_legal(l or r or d or u)` was only passing the first truthy value to the `self.is_legal` method, not all of them.

Comment: Great! Yeah, i was trying use any/all but didn't think about adding for. Thank you!

Comment: You mean if `self.is_legal` were a lambda function?  Sure, it would be the same as what I posted.  Lambda's are just like normal functions and can be called anywhere they can.

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant. Thank you very much. Have a great day and Happy Easter!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tuple or set:

```
if False in (self.is_legal(l), self.is_legal(u), self.is_legal(r), self.is_legal(d)):

if {False} <= {self.is_legal(l), self.is_legal(u), self.is_legal(r)}:
```

Extending this idea a bit further:

```
if {False} <= {self.is_legal(var) for var in (l, u, r, d)}:
```

Or using the fact that an empty list or set or whatever is false:

```
if [var for var in (l, u, r, d) if self.is_legal(var) is False]:
```

I guess it all depends on what you consider to be "pretty".

Answer (score 0):

An empty list in Python is false.

You can produce an empty list with a comprehension and a conditional like so:

```
>>> def is_legal(x):
...    return x>5
... 
>>> bool([x for x in (1,2,3,4) if is_legal(x)])
False
>>> bool([x for x in (1,2,3,4,6) if is_legal(x)])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance the readability of your code by employing the `any` function. In the following code, a generator expression within the `any` function is used to determine whether any of the moves conforms to the legality condition specified by `self.is_legal`.

```
if not any(self.is_legal(move) for move in (l, u, r, d)):
```